# curl calling REST API response into a file

Tags: rest, curl

I am using curl to call a REST API. The REST call returns a file mar21.tar.gz

But the format of the file is data but it has to be in gzip format for me to run tar -xvf on it.

How can I get the file to save in the original format in which it is returned.

curl -u #{user}:#{password} -k -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -o #{tmp_dir}/#{filename} -X GET #{url}

Comment: "...the format of the file is data..." What? You're expecting to get a *.tar.gz but you're getting... something else?

Comment: Yes, I see that the file is getting saved as mar15.tar.gz, when I say tar -xvf mar15.tar.gz, it says not in gzip format, so I tried to see the format of the file by typing file mar15.tar.gz, it says data

Comment: What does it look like if you `cat` it?

Comment: cat displays some garbage characters. is there a way to specify the content type of the output?

Comment: How big is the file? Add `-D -` to your curl command to dump the HTTP headers you're getting back from the remote server, and post them here.

Comment: -D options fails with error NSS: Client certificate not found (nickname not specified) Is there a way to specify contenttype of the response coming back.

Comment: There's no standard way to tell the server what to give you back, but it's possible that the server was programmed to adjust its output based on one of the GET parameters you're passing. Also, it looks like you missed the second minus -- it's `minus D space minus`

Comment: Or you could do `-D headers` and curl will dump the headers to a file named headers.

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 03 Sep 2015 20:22:42 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/gz
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=M1_jdk-7u55-fcs-bin-b13-linux-x64-17_mar_2014.tar.gz
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 27af2010-385c-4bee-b240-7622b5f80a16-00000097
Set-Cookie: ICSAUTH=AReU4Ckihar8u9jo-cXFzc-VyFf3S3liE4xgRqIoKK8Kg3bZtW9A!37635052; path=/icsapis; HttpOnly

Comment: When I make the rest api call from a browser, the downloaded file is fine & I am able to tar it. But when I invoke it from curl, the file downloads but I am not able to tar -xvf the file. Please help.

Comment: What's the file size when you download from curl? What's the file size when you download from browser?

Comment: Run `md5sum` on each file. Do the hashes match?

Comment: md5sum 15.4.1_jdk-7u55-fcs-bin-b13-linux-x64-17_mar_2014.tar.gz
34f879ea0d88a464b453eca213a75557  15.4.1_jdk-7u55-fcs-bin-b13-linux-x64-17_mar_2014.tar.gz
[t1@den00bzq tmp]$ md5sum dl.tar.gz                                       d1e4a27e22550f8907602bed3ebd63c2  dl.tar.gz

Comment: seems like the header might be wrong in the downloaded file. How to check & fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl -u #{user}:#{password} -k -i -H "Content-type: application/json" -o #{tmp_dir}/#{filename} -X GET #{url} > mar21.tar.gz
```